# Mediawiki extension on Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I search the best practice to add extension on my container MediaWiki.
Create a dockerfile with the download of the extension or add the extension file on the volume data?
Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: Have you checked: [adding additional libraries](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mediawiki/#adding-additional-libraries--extensions) which points you to [this](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/31280550a3c7104fef824450753844d2f3d917be/php/README.md#how-to-install-more-php-extensions)?

Comment: Yes, but it's for php extension and not for mediawiki extension. I need to do the same thing for mediawiki extension?

Comment: I answered a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533718/1131145